# How to do Time Estimation in new Projects

Tags: project-management, time-estimation

I am new for this Responsibility, however I have analyzed many projects as a Software Developer and given time estimation of the task.

But it is difficult when you are Team leader and don't know about your developers skills. because sometimes it requires R & D stuff. So at that time do not judge the estimation.

There are also some models available for this like 'COCOMO Model'.

But Is it feasible to use this kind of model or any other technique for better Time Estimation.

Comment: I doubt that this question will garner a lot of response, and given that I am tossing in but a comment, I will have a limited amount of characters for entry.  The main problem is that programming is an interesting combination of standard math/science and art.  Given this, it becomes very difficult to give timelines for atypical problems in program.  All typical programming problems have been solved.  Want to create a blog?  Go to wordpress.com, etc.  Want to solve a problem for a new webapp that isn't available yet?  Art.  Always multiply what you think by at least two, and good luck.

Comment: thanks. for your valuable comments.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming in general. You may be able to get help on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Describe the task to each programmer and ask him to give three times. How long does each of them think the team will take.

ultrafast time, likely time and worst case time.

do the following sum for all programmers

1 * ultra + 3 * likely + 1 * worst

divide by

(ammount of programmers * 5)

Use this as your estimation.